# open a contextmanager but only if not provided by the caller

Tags: python, contextmanager

This is a bit of a contrived example, my actual use case is with (mostly read-only) database connections - if a connection is not provided, open one.

I've changed that to an open file handle that was provided by a `with open(xxx) as fo`.  The idea is that I have some functions that may need to do some work - if their caller has already given them a context-managed object (the file handle in this case), use it.  Else create with it a local context manager.

#### conceptually this is what I want, but it fails as expected:

```
def write_it(name, fo=None):
    if not fo:
       with open(name,"w") as fo:
            #I'd want to keep `fo` but it wont work
            pass

    #assume this is a lot of complex code

    #if fo was opened here, it will have been closed already
    fo.write(name)


name = "works_w_context.txt"
with open(name, "w") as fo:
    write_it(name, fo)
    fo.write("\n and it still should be open")

#this fails, as expected
name = "error_wo_context.txt"
write_it(name)
```

As expected, I got an error when I did not provide an open file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_182_context.py", line 21, in <module>
    write_it(name)
  File "test_182_context.py", line 12, in write_it
    fo.write(data)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

(venv38) myuser@test_182_context$ dir *.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  staff  52 Oct  1 17:26 works_w_context.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  staff   0 Oct  1 17:26 error_wo_context.txt
```

#### My workaround - is there a better way using `contextlib` module?

The only way I've found to do this is by creating a public stub function that opens the file if needed and then calls the actual real function with a file handle.

But as you can see I have now repeated the function signature 4 times.  Sure, `*args` and `**kwargs` can help, a bit, but they also make code harder to follow.

```
def _write_it(name, fo=None):
    #assume this is a lot of complex code
    data = "some very complicated calculations taking many lines"    
    fo.write(data)


def write_it(name, fo=None):
    if not fo:
       with open(name,"w") as fo:
            _write_it(name, fo)
    else:
        _write_it(name, fo)



name = "works2_w_context.txt"
with open(name, "w") as fo:
    write_it(name, fo)
    fo.write("\n and it still should be open")

#this fails, as expected
name = "works2_wo_context.txt"
write_it(name)
```

and yes, it works:

```
(venv38) myuser@test_182_context$ py test_182_context_2.py
(venv38) myuser@test_182_context$ dir *.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  staff  52 Oct  1 17:29 works2_w_context.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  staff  52 Oct  1 17:29 works2_wo_context.txt
```

Someone asked a question earlier today and a comment mentioned [contextlib.nullcontext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext)

> Return a context manager that returns enter_result from **enter**, but otherwise does nothing. It is intended to be used as a stand-in for an optional context manager.

It kinda *looks* like it's related what I am after but at the same time it doesn't look like it will address the core problem with nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an exit stack to conditionally add a new context manager for a file you open yourself.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

def write_it(name, fo=None):
    with ExitStack() as es:
        if fo is None:
            fo = es.enter_context(open(name, "w"))
    
        data = ...
        fo.write()
```

If the exit stack is empty, there is nothing to be done when the `with` statement exits. Only a newly opened file will be added to the stack, to be closed when the `with` statement completes.

---

You can also use a null context manager if `fo` is not `None`:

```
from contextlib import nullcontext

def write_it(name, fo=None):
    if fo is None:
        # With no file received, open a new one and use it
        # as the context manager
        cm = open(name, "w")
    else:
        # Create a do-nothing context manager that won't close
        # the received file.
        cm = nullcontext(fo)

    # Get an open file handle from the defined context manager
    with cm as f:
        data = ...
        f.write(data)
```

A null context manager's `__enter__` method returns the wrapped object, but its `__exit__` method does nothing.

Comment: I could not get the nullcontext version to work `AttributeError("'nullcontext' object has no attribute 'write'")`.  The file *is* there as `fo.enter_result` but the bare `fo` can't write.  However, using the exitstack version, after correcting your exitstack condition to `if fo is None:` instead of the opposite, does work.

Comment: OK, I see what I did wrong. My test accidentally used `f.write`, not `fo.write`, so I was picking up the global file handle passed as an argument. Fixing that reproduces your error. The problem is that the `nullcontext` object itself doesn't have a `write` method; the object it *returns* (the file handle) does. `with fo as fo:` fixes it, but that's a bit ugly. Let me see if I can find a cleaner fix.

Comment: I think the key is to make a strict logical distinction between the file and the context manager. In the case of a locally opened file, they will be one and the same. In the case of a passed-in file, they will be distinct.

Comment: I got the nullcontext working too, by picking up the write on its own: `write = getattr(fo,"write", None) or fo.enter_result.write`.  then just `write(data)`.  the key is that by nesting it under your original `with fo:` you leave the context manager alone and you just pick up the write directly on the local open, or from the `enter_result`, but you don't need to fiddle with a "special" cm.

Comment: If you're OK I can just edit it back to what you had, along with the adjustment.  Then I can accept the answer - as it did solve my question.  I just don't want to accept while it has has small problems.

Comment: OK, edited and accepted.  BTW, got a **strong** preference for nullcontext on the basis of clarity of intent.  ExitStack looks very powerful in capabilities, but less obvious.